# PyQt5 - Create a check item in a column of a table widget even with the number of rows varying from a spinbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to PyQt5 and I'm using Qtdesigner to develop an interface.

I am controlling the number of rows of a Table Widget from the spinbox. However, when changing the number of rows I need to keep the check option for column a.

I managed to change the number of rows according to valueChanged in the spinbox, but the loop I created to create the check regardless of the number of rows did not work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(519, 468)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 131, 41, 31))
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 2)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 341, 101))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 519, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged['int'].connect(self.tableWidget.setRowCount)

        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, item)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "d"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "e"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "d"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "e"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "a"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "c"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I can see check boxes in the picture. Can you explain exactly what is not working as expected?

Comment: Do you mean that when you add a new row it doesn't get a checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems like you're editing the output of a `pyuic` generated file, or you're trying to mimic its behavior. In any case, this is something that should *never* be done.

Those files are meant to be left **as they are**, and you should only use them as modules; to know how to correctly do this, read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). If you're trying to mimic their behavior, well, you shouldn't: the way pyuic files are treated is only considered as an "interpretation layer" in order to create the GUI objects and make them accessible from python. If you're building the GUI from code, just subclass the QWidget you want to use (QWidget, QDialog or QMainWindow, usually).

Now, the problem is that whenever [`setRowCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount) is called...:

> [it] Sets the number of rows in this table's model to rows. If this is less than rowCount(), the data in the unwanted rows **is discarded**.

This obviously means that, if you're removing rows, you're losing all items in that row (including the fact that they are checkable at all).

To correctly update the contents and add checkable items, you'll need to do that in a specific method that dynamically removes or adds items.

In the next example I'll show how to correctly implement this (and in an easier, clearer way):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.spin)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(2, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        for col, label in enumerate(('a', 'c')):
            header = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(label)
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(col, header)
            if col:
                continue
            for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
                self.table.setItem(row, col, item)

        self.spin.setValue(self.table.rowCount())
        self.spin.valueChanged.connect(self.setRowCount)

    def setRowCount(self, count):
        if count == self.table.rowCount():
            return
        # if there are too many rows, remove them
        while self.table.rowCount() > count:
            self.table.removeRow(self.table.rowCount() - 1)
        # if rows are going to be added, create checkable items for them
        while self.table.rowCount() < count:
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(row)
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As a side note, a couple of considerations:

- a layout manager should always be used for widgets, otherwise the contents might become invisible or won't adjust their position;
- you're defining `retranslateUi` twice; I suppose that's something that remained from editing the pyuic file, but, in any case, redifining a function with the same name results in overwriting it (unless each of them have an unique decorator)